# How do I pass in a 1d array to sklearn's LabelEncoder?

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn, python-polars

I'm following along an [Uber-Lyft price prediction notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/danielbeltsazar/uber-lyft-price-prediction) on Kaggle, but I'm trying to use the Polars module.

In cell 43 where they use sklearn's LabelEncoder, they have the following loop that appears to loop through each feature, except for price, and encodes it:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

df_cat_encode= df_cat.copy()
for col in df_cat_encode.select_dtypes(include='O').columns:
    df_cat_encode[col]=le.fit_transform(df_cat_encode[col])
```

The data being passed through looks like this:

| source | destination | cab_type | name | short_summary | icon | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Haymarket Square | North Station | Lyft | Shared | Mostly Cloudy | partly-cloudy-night | 5.0 |
| Haymarket Square | North Station | Lyft | Lux | Rain | rain | 11.0 |
| Haymarket Square | North Station | Lyft | Lyft | Clear | clear-night | 7.0 |
| Haymarket Square | North Station | Lyft | Lux Black XL | Clear | clear-night | 26.0 |

and the label encoded result looks like this:

637975 rows x 7 columns

| source | destination | cab_type | name | short_summary | icon | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 7 | 0 | 7 | 4 | 5 | 5.0 |
| 5 | 7 | 0 | 2 | 8 | 6 | 11.0 |
| 5 | 7 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 1 | 7.0 |
| 5 | 7 | 0 | 4 | 6 | 1 | 26.0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The problem I'm having is when I try to build the same loop with Polars syntax like

```
for col in df_cat_encode.select(["source","destination","cab_type","name","short_summary","icon"]).columns:
    df_cat_encode.with_column(le.fit_transform(col))
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py", line 115, in fit_transform
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 1038, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead.
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this encoding is the equivalent of a "dense" ranking.

```
>>> df_cat_encode
   source  destination  cab_type  name  short_summary  icon  price
0       0            0         0     3              1     1      5.0
1       0            0         0     0              2     2      11.0
2       0            0         0     2              0     0      7.0
3       0            0         0     1              0     0      26.0
```

Which you can do in polars using `.rank()`:

```
>>> df.with_columns(pl.all().exclude("price").rank(method="dense") - 1)
shape: (4, 7)
┌────────┬─────────────┬──────────┬──────┬───────────────┬──────┬───────┐
│ source | destination | cab_type | name | short_summary | icon | price │
│ ---    | ---         | ---      | ---  | ---           | ---  | ---   │
│ u32    | u32         | u32      | u32  | u32           | u32  | f64   │
╞════════╪═════════════╪══════════╪══════╪═══════════════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 0      | 0           | 0        | 3    | 1             | 1    | 5.0   │
├────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼──────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┤
│ 0      | 0           | 0        | 0    | 2             | 2    | 11.0  │
├────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼──────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┤
│ 0      | 0           | 0        | 2    | 0             | 0    | 7.0   │
├────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼──────┼───────────────┼──────┼───────┤
│ 0      | 0           | 0        | 1    | 0             | 0    | 26.0  │
└─//─────┴─//──────────┴─//───────┴─//───┴─//────────────┴─//───┴─//────┘
```

Comment: Perfect! That worked beautifully. May I ask what the ```- 1```  is for?

Comment: The rank scores start at `1` by default. If you want `0` based - you can minus 1.